# Забирать данные из contact form 7 на странице в форму в popup. WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

У меня на странице есть несколько форм с чекбоксами.
Когда пользователь отмечает несколько чекбоксов и отправляет форму, мне необходимо чтобы появлялась форма попап, в которой он вносит дополнительную информацию, скажем имя и телефон.

Как это можно реализовать? Можно ли как-то связать 2 формы или нужно передавать значение инпута на странице в форму в попапе? Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

> Как это можно реализовать?

Это называется многошаговые формы, multistep. Для CF7 есть несколько дополнений для этого. Напр: https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-multi-step-module/

Попап же - другая история. Для этого нужно подключать латйбокс/фансибокс.

Однако в целом это очень плохое решение - второй шаг, где нужно дописывать контакты.

Comment: И как же связать мультишаговость форм со страница и формы в попап? Я же думал что можно забирать значение инпута перед запуском fancybox и передавать его в поле, которое находится в попапе. Можно же так ?

Comment: Это зависит от того что УЖЕ работает на сайте для кач-ве лайбокаса/фансибокса (А оно наверняка уже есть). Ибо плодить разные - источник проблема.

Comment: Я сам всё устанавливаю, натягиваю тему на движок. Суть не в скрипте попапа, а в том, как в него передавать инфу.

Comment: Об этом я и написал в ответе